# jQuery keyup function not executing

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have this code :

```
<script>
     $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
               alert('Handler for .keyup() called.');
     });
</script>
```

and this input :

```
<input id='searchInput' type='text' placeholder='Search other alumni users' />
```

but when I press a key, the alert doesn't come up...
I've included the jQuery script already.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change your code to

```
$(function(){ // this will be called when the DOM is ready
  $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
    alert('Handler for .keyup() called.');
  });
});
```

to ensure the DOM element exists when you build the jQuery set.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much for this. I have been pulling out my hair trying to figure out why my code doesn't trigger. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 10):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
    alert('Handler for .keyup() called.');
  });
});
```

Or

```
$(function() { 
  $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
    alert('Handler for .keyup() called.');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`keyup`/`keydown` seem to only work on elements that are present at `document.ready`.

If you are triggering your event from elements that were altered or injected post pageload, these events will not fire.

Finding or creating a parent of the element to be watched that's present on load then setting the event to trigger from that parent element can bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had multiple functions within the `$(document).ready(function () {});`

By changing the order of my Keyup functions i.e. placing them at the top... within document ready seemed to do the trick. My guess is that one of the other functions was breaking the keyup function for what ever reason?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    jQuery(".divForinput1 > input").keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    jQuery( ".divForinput2 > input" ).val( value );
    }).keyup();

//the .keyup on the end maybe what many are missing
```